# "Bad address" error when accessing /dev/clipboard in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I like to use /dev/clipboard for moving content easily between Windows and Cygwin's command-line tools. It seems like Cygwin has problems with large clipboard contents, though. I get an error like this when I try to access /dev/clipboard after copying a large amount of text on the Windows side:

```
$ wc -c /dev/clipboard
wc: /dev/clipboard: Bad address
573440 /dev/clipboard
```

Is there a fixed buffer size for the clipboard that I can somehow increase? Or is this some other issue entirely?

Comment: How much is a lot in your case i.e. at what amount of data does it struggle? The example you show above shows ~560kB, but I just tried with 8 megs and it seemed to work just fine. Also, just for curiosity's sake, could you try using `getclip` and `putclip` instead of handling the `/dev/clipboard` device and see if that makes any difference? I doubt it, they probably do the exact same thing, but I'm curious. `cat large.txt | putclip ; getclip | wc -c`

Comment: I played around in Notepad for a bit, and found that at 16384 characters, it works fine. At 16385 characters, it breaks with the "Bad address" error. I tried getclip and putclip, though, and those worked fine with even 100 MB of text! Put that in as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `/dev/clipboard` device is problematic for you, but I do know that using the `putclip` and `getclip` utilities should be able to handle the job. I regularly use them with multiple megs worth of data and have never run into any trouble.

```
$ cat large.txt | putclip

$ getclip | wc -c
8665361
```

They come with the `cygutils` package... http://cygwin.com/packages/cygutils/