# Cygwin copy to Clipboard when contacted to a server

Tags: windows, cygwin, clipboard, cut-and-paste

When I want to copy some text/files to clipboard using Cygwin I use

```
echo filename | clip
```

Which works great.

When I want to do the same thing after contacting to a (SSH) server, I get an error message.
Apparently this is Cygwin specific, and has to do with something related to graphical interface not working on my instance of Cygwin.

So my question is how I should get the same thing to work on a server (I want to be able to do it using keyboard only).

One thing that can be mentioned about my issue is that "getclip" and "putclip" (e.g. as described here: ["Bad address" error when accessing /dev/clipboard in Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/552288/bad-address-error-when-accessing-dev-clipboard-in-cygwin) ) does not work for me, while just "clip" does.